# How to split string using istringstream with other delimiter than whitespace?

Tags: c++

The following trick using `istringstream` to split a string with white spaces.

```
int main() {
    string sentence("Cpp is fun");
    istringstream in(sentence);
    vector<string> vec = vector<string>(istream_iterator<string>(in), istream_iterator<string>());
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a similar trick to split a string with `any` delimiter? For instance, `|` in "Cpp|is|fun".

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string

Comment: An (IMO) more relevant answer would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338827/reading-formatted-data-with-cs-stream-operator-when-data-has-spaces/2343074#2343074. Actually most of these are roughly similar: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A179910+imbue

Comment: should be: "vector<string> vec( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );"  as in your example, you'd be making a instansiation, then invoking the copy-constructor of std::vector.

Comment: @Ben Tou CHeh: the one you mentioned is the most vexing parse in C++. You might want to take a look at this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511733/cannot-access-vector-when-constructing-with-istream-iterator-range

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Ryan Li: Thanks a lot guys ;)

Comment: @Chan: Adding an extra pair of round brackets for compile-time purposes is a small price to pay when compared to the other options which will incure a run-time penalty each and every time it is called.

Comment: In GCC, the only you nead is to add delimeters as second parameter to std::istream_iterator constructor:


    istream_iterator<string>(in, " ,|")

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking the istringstream approach is slow/inefficient and requires at least as much memory as the string itself *(what happens when you have a very large string?)*. The [C++ String Toolkit Library (StrTk)](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) has the following solution to your problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include "strtk.hpp"
int main()
{
   std::string sentence1( "Cpp is fun" );
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
   strtk::parse(sentence1," ",vec);

   std::string sentence2( "Cpp,is|fun" );
   std::deque<std::string> deq;
   strtk::parse(sentence2,"|,",deq);

   return 0;
}
```

More examples can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx)

Comment: This does not answer the question because the question is about splitting using stream. Difference is in streaming. This could be network stream or stream loading from disk while you parsing. It could be large enough.

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::istringstream iss { "Cpp|is|fun" };

  std::string s;
  while ( std::getline( iss, s, '|' ) )
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/sMGPk4)

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a regex to find the "|" and split the surrounding elements into an array. It then prints each of those elements, using `cout`, in a `for` loop.

This method allows for splitting with regex as an alternative.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
    
using namespace std;


vector<string> splitter(string in_pattern, string& content){
    vector<string> split_content;

    regex pattern(in_pattern);
    copy( sregex_token_iterator(content.begin(), content.end(), pattern, -1),
    sregex_token_iterator(),back_inserter(split_content));  
    return split_content;
}
    
int main()
{   

    string sentence = "This|is|the|sentence";
    //vector<string> words = splitter(R"(\s+)", sentence); // seperate by space
    vector<string> words = splitter(R"(\|)", sentence);

    for (string word: words){cout << word << endl;}

}
```